# iPhone personal hotspot sharing Wi-Fi connection instead of 4G

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone, tethering

I have an iPhone 5s and it's connected to a Wi-Fi network. I have a personal hotspot set up. I'm currently using this hotspot on my laptop and am just wondering if it is uses my phone's data or the Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99706/can-you-share-a-wi-fi-connection-using-personal-hotspot